# Custom image markers with leaflet not displaying image

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have some code that tries to set a user's marker to his profile image. The image is a JPG, which I believe is the problem, because I don't think that leaflet supports JPGs. But just in case here is my code. There is no error in the console, the marker just remains the default marker.

```
var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
function addMarkerGroup(lat_ret,lon_ret,map,user, profile_pic) {
  console.log(profile_pic);
  var profilePicIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: profile_pic,
    iconSize: [50, 50], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor: [25, 25], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });
  map.removeLayer(markers);
  markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
  var marker = L.marker([lat_ret, lon_ret]).addTo(map).bindPopup("User:" + user,{autoClose: false,autoPan: false,icon: profilePicIcon}).openPopup();
  markers.addLayer(marker);
  map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the icon in your `L.Marker` options:

```
var marker = L.marker([lat_ret, lon_ret], {icon: profilePicIcon})
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have the icon defined, however, do I have to declare a new featuregroup and layer or can I just use  var marker = L.marker([lat_ret, lon_ret]).addTo(map)

Comment: That was it for me Thanks!